# What is the meaning of that code?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Could anyone explain me what is the meaning of that code?

```
\foreach \r in {45,135}
        \foreach \i [evaluate={\s=30;}] in {0,2,...,30}
          \fill [black, fill opacity=1/50] 
            (0,0) -- (\r+\s-\i:2 and 2/3) 
            arc (\r+\s-\i:\r-\s+\i:2 and 2/3)  -- cycle;
```

Comment: For one thing, it means whoever wrote it REALLY likes to use loops.  Seriously, `\foreach \r in {45,135}`?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 7):

Let's open [`TikZ` documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgf).

Let's write `\foreach` into `find` field. We'll find two `\foreach` in cover code, let's forget them. The third appearance ([pag 26](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgf#page=26))
) is an hyperlink to chapter ["83 Repeating Things: The Foreach Statement"](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgf#page=901). Let's read this chapter because it explains what `\foreach` means, and also what's `evaluate={\s=30}`.

Once `\foreach` has been understood, let's look for next command: `\fill`. We find a reference to this command in first page of `foreach` chapter. Let's click on it and we are driven to page 164. This reference is not too clear. We better look into table of contents (ToC) where we find section "15.5 Filling a Path". After that, `\fill` is already understood.

Next one: `fill opacity`. According to ToC, it's explained in section "15.5.3 Graphic Parameters: Fill Opacity", but this one only drive us to section "23 Transparency" where we can understand what `opacity` means.

The next one `(\r+\s-\i:2 and 2/3)` is a little bit difficult to find. With a little of imagination we reduce to something like `(a:x and y)`. Even with this format it's difficult to find on pgfmanual. This is one reason to carefully read all wonderful tutorials in chapters 2 to 6. In any case, you can find what's that in section "13.2.1 Canvas, XYZ, and Polar Coordinate Systems".

After that we just need to look for `arc` ("14.7 The Arc Operation") and `--cycle` (page 36).

Once we have read all these sections it's easy to understand that posted code is just a repetition of a `fill` command. Let's try to write the first one (`\r=45`, `\i=0` and `\s=30`):

```
\fill [black, fill opacity=1/50] 
        (0,0) -- (75:2 and 2/3) 
        arc (75:15:2 and 2/3)  -- cycle;
```

This means `fill` an ellipse sector. The ellipse has long radius 2 and short one 2/3. The sector starts at angle 75 and finishes at angle 15. With `fill opacity=1` results in

[image]

Following iteration will cover a narrower sector from 73 to 17 degrees, and so on. As all sectors are drawn over previous ones, the area around central angles (45 and 135) goes darker as [knut's result shows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/406732/1952)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is alrady the answer or just a refinement of the question:

The code contains tikz-command, so you can just try it in a ^MWE (minimal working example) with a `tikzpicture`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \r in {45,135}
        \foreach \i [evaluate={\s=30;}] in {0,2,...,30}
          \fill [black, fill opacity=1/50] 
            (0,0) -- (\r+\s-\i:2 and 2/3) 
            arc (\r+\s-\i:\r-\s+\i:2 and 2/3)  -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: I think the question has an implicit how it works

Comment: I was not sure, if I should answer or if I should modify the question.    But I didn't want to change the whole question. Let's wait for a response of the questioner and maybe I can delete this anser.

Comment: you can first ask the OP instead